# Javascript: Geolocation values in global variable

Tags: javascript, geolocation, global-variables

I'm working on a little web application which uses GPS. It uses Javascript to accomplish this. What I'm doing:

- Defining an global array "positionCoords" with 2 empty indexes
  (latitude / longitude).
- On document ready, I am requesting latitude / longitude with the function "getGeoLocation()".
- After the request, I am doing an simple console.log of the array. The array indexes are still empty.
- Executing console.log(positionCoords) in the webbrowser console, gives me the correct values.

Could this has something to do with asynchronously? I'm quite new to this feature, any help would be appreciated!

```
// global variables
var positionCoords = {};
positionCoords['latitude'] = null;
positionCoords['longitude'] = null;

/*
 on document ready, excecute
  */
$(document).ready(function() {
    getGeolocation();
    console.log(positionCoords);
});

/*
 check if geolocation is supported and allowed, get coordinates
 */
function getGeolocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        // geolocation is available
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            function(position) {
                // get coordinates
                positionCoords['latitude'] = position.coords.latitude;
                positionCoords['longitude'] = position.coords.longitude;
                return true;
            },
            function(error){
                handleGeolocationErrors(error);
                return false;
            }
        );
    } else {
        // geolocation is not available
        console.log("Browser does not support geolocation services.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try the DEMO on my answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/38674753/747579

Answer (score 0):

## [DEMO with Google Map](http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/jqv1L6cb/2/)

Since it is **ASYNC** call, you need to pass function-callback to `getGeolocation`, then , you will call it like the follwong :

### ON Calling :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    getGeolocation(function(coords){
          console.log(coords); 
           //====The resof your code which dependent on `coords` SHALL be here
           //......

   },function(err){console.log(err)});

});
```

To be able to call it like the above , you need to modify the implementation of `getGeolocation` by passing it two parameters  :

1. Function Callback **onSuccess**.
2. Function Callback **onError**

### Implementation :

```
/*
 check if geolocation is supported and allowed, get coordinates
 */
function getGeolocation(fnsuccess,fnerror) {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        // geolocation is available
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            function(position) {
               if(typeof fnsuccess==='function'){
                        fnsuccess.call(null,position.coords); //--Call CallBack On Success
                }
            },
            function(error){
                if(typeof fnerror ==='function'){
                      fnerror.call(null,error); //--Call CallBack On Error
                }
            }
        );
    } else {
        // geolocation is not available
        console.log("Browser does not support geolocation services.");
        return false;

    }
}
```

## [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/jqv1L6cb/) :

the DEMO will ask you to share your location , if you accept , check the console of your browser , you will get `Coords` as you expect

## [DEMO with Google Map](http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/jqv1L6cb/2/)